# How can I get mouse coordinates relative to the page rather than relative to the screen in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the location of the cursor relative to the page of my website rather than relative to the screen its being shown on

```
<script>
function show_coords(event) {
document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = "X= " + event.clientX + "<br>Y= " + event.clientY;
}
</script>

<body> 
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
}

.main {
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
overflow: auto;
cursor: move;
}

.main img {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
position: fixed;
display: block;
width: 150px;
height: 100%;
top: 15%; 
left: 0%;
font-size: 100%;
z-index: 3; 
}
</style>
<div class="main dragscroll" ondblclick="show_coords(event)">
<img id="map" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/f6ccc989-c4e6-4876-925d- 
5c75e6d3cf19%2FRed-Dead-Redemption-2-Full-World-Map.png?1547325193157"/>
</div>
<div id="sidebar"></div> 
</body>
```

V more details in this image V

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) which is relative to the top left of the fully rendered content area in the browser.

Also [screenX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/screenX) is another option

The difference between the two is that screenX consider the top left of the physical monitor where as `pageX` is relative to the left edge of the entire document

Comment: I tried 'page' just now but it doesn't seem to change the result.